# Is there a cli equivalent of the web ui with underspecification?

Tags: 8, drush, configuration, external-scripts

## background

I run `drush cget markdown.settings` and see:

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - markdown
parser:
  id: michelf/php-markdown-extra
  render_strategy:
    type: none
  settings:
    code_attr_on_pre: false
    code_class_prefix: ''
    empty_element_suffix: ' />'
    enhanced_ordered_list: true
    fn_backlink_class: footnote-backref
    fn_backlink_html: '&#8617;&#xFE0E;'
    fn_backlink_label: ''
    fn_backlink_title: ''
    fn_id_prefix: ''
    fn_link_class: footnote-ref
    fn_link_title: ''
    hard_wrap: false
    hashtag_protection: false
    no_entities: false
    no_markup: false
    omit_footnotes: false
    predef_abbr: {  }
    predef_titles: {  }
    predef_urls: {  }
    tab_width: 4
    table_align_class_tmpl: ''
```

I visit https://drupal8.example.org/admin/config/content/markdown

In the "Parser" tab, I select `CommonMark (1.5.3)`.

In the "Render Strategy" tab, I select `Filter Output`.

I save the changes.

I run `drush cget markdown.settings` and see:

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - markdown
parser:
  id: league/commonmark
  render_strategy:
    type: filter_output
    allowed_html: '<a href hreflang> <abbr> <blockquote cite> <br> <cite> <code> <div> <em> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6> <hr> <img alt height src width> <li> <ol start type=''1 A I''> <p> <pre> <span> <strong> <ul type>'
    plugins:
      - markdown
      - bootstrap
  settings:
    allow_unsafe_links: true
    enable_em: true
    enable_strong: true
    html_input: allow
    max_nesting_level: 0
    renderer:
      block_separator: \n
      inner_separator: \n
      soft_break: \n
    unordered_list_markers:
      - '-'
      - '*'
      - +
    use_asterisk: true
    use_underscore: true
```

Notice that `parser.render_strategy.allowed_html` and `parser.render_strategy.plugins` were added and that `parser.settings` has changed, even though I did not edit them in the web UI.

---

I revert the changes by visiting: https://drupal8.example.org/admin/config/content/markdown

In the "Parser" tab, I select `PHP Markdown Extra (1.9.0)`.

In the "Render Strategy" tab, I select `None`.

I save the changes.

I run `drush cget markdown.settings` and see the original settings:

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - markdown
parser:
  id: michelf/php-markdown-extra
  render_strategy:
    type: none
  settings:
    code_attr_on_pre: false
    code_class_prefix: ''
    empty_element_suffix: ' />'
    enhanced_ordered_list: true
    fn_backlink_class: footnote-backref
    fn_backlink_html: '&#8617;&#xFE0E;'
    fn_backlink_label: ''
    fn_backlink_title: ''
    fn_id_prefix: ''
    fn_link_class: footnote-ref
    fn_link_title: ''
    hard_wrap: false
    hashtag_protection: false
    no_entities: false
    no_markup: false
    omit_footnotes: false
    predef_abbr: {  }
    predef_titles: {  }
    predef_urls: {  }
    tab_width: 4
    table_align_class_tmpl: ''
```

Notice that `parser.render_strategy.allowed_html` and `parser.render_strategy.plugins` were removed and that `parser.settings` has changed back, even though I did not edit them in the web UI.

## the problem

However, these associated changes do not happen if I change with drush:

```
$ drush cset markdown.settings parser.id league/commonmark
$ drush cset markdown.settings parser.render_strategy.type filter_output
$ drush cget markdown.settings
dependencies:
  module:
    - markdown
parser:
  id: league/commonmark
  render_strategy:
    type: filter_output
  settings:
    code_attr_on_pre: false
    code_class_prefix: ''
    empty_element_suffix: ' />'
    enhanced_ordered_list: true
    fn_backlink_class: footnote-backref
    fn_backlink_html: '&#8617;&#xFE0E;'
    fn_backlink_label: ''
    fn_backlink_title: ''
    fn_id_prefix: ''
    fn_link_class: footnote-ref
    fn_link_title: ''
    hard_wrap: false
    hashtag_protection: false
    no_entities: false
    no_markup: false
    omit_footnotes: false
    predef_abbr: {  }
    predef_titles: {  }
    predef_urls: {  }
    tab_width: 4
    table_align_class_tmpl: ''
$
```

In particular, notice that `parser.render_strategy.allowed_html` and `parser.render_strategy.plugins` were not added and that `parser.settings` has not changed.

Using the web UI, these associated changes do not have to be specified explicitly.

Is there a way to make similar under-specified config changes by cli?

For clarification, I use `drush` simply as an example of a cli. Using other non-interactive commandline tools would be fine.

Comment: I think your question is “Can config:set do the same operations as what a module can do in its configuration form(s)?”

Comment: @mradcliffe not quite. I don't care what the commandline tool is, I just want it to be non-interactive so I can script it. However I don't want to have to explicitly specify all kinds of additional data that the interactive web ui doesn't require.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what exactly you want to achieve and also why?

Comment: @leymannx I am writing a shell script to build a drupal 8 website from an existing drupal 6 website. Every time I notice something broken with the migration, I want  to modify the script with non-interactive commands that fix the problem. Currently, configuring settings by web UI is not non-interactive.

Answer (score 3):

Using Form API and Configuration are two fundamentally different things:

1. A module configuration forms in Drupal are (usually) provided by that module extending ConfigFormBase. A “Form” is just a specially-crafted render array that on submit (and validate) calls methods on the Form controller class. A module author can do whatever they want in that submit/validate based on user's input. This can include calling set/get on Config objects as they need to, and then calling save. **Form submit methods and callbacks can do any number of complexity rather than a simple operation on a config object.**
2. The Drush config:set (cset) command sets a value to a single config key. It does not do any logic or form submission. One needs to know exactly the configuration that needs to be saved. **The config commands are doing create, read, update, and delete on the config object defined by the provided key.**

The answer is **no**. There is not a way for Drush to determine what the module is actually doing in its form submit.

In order to replicate what a module does in logic, then the same logic must be traced and values changed accordingly before trying to save the configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't have to be drush (that's just an obvious example of a cli). Given the web UI is an HTTP GET, manual modification of some of the data received, followed by a POST, I had hoped there was a simple way to cause the equivalent of this GET/modify/POST non-interactively.

Comment: Unfortunately not so simple. Every form/module can be different. As a module developer, I do the same thing and have some logic in my form submit that saves things.

Comment: please review my answer - in what situations may it fail?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to update ancillary settings the same as the web UI:

```
drush php << 'EOD'
  use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormState;
  use \Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext;

  $v['parser']['id'] = 'league/commonmark';
  $v['parser']['render_strategy']['type'] = 'filter_output';

  #$v['parser']['id'] = 'michelf/php-markdown-extra';
  #$v['parser']['render_strategy']['type'] = 'none';

  $s = new FormState();
  $s->setValues($v);
  $c = new RenderContext();
  $r = \Drupal::service('renderer');
  $r->executeInRenderContext($c, function() use ($s) {
    \Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm(
      '\Drupal\markdown\Form\SettingsForm',$s
    );
  });
EOD
```

Comment: I think that could fail for other forms that have required fields without default values set, but that's fairly impressive. You might create drush commands to get a form and set an arbitrary form.